# Install a new font on AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm installing Imagemagick on AWS Lambda and it appears that the fonts that Imagemagick normally uses aren't preinstalled, how can I add additional fonts?

Comment: Does it work if you provide the path the font file (with suffix) and not just the name?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I just got to work for custom fonts on AWS Lambda with pandoc/xelatex. I assume you can do something very similar to get Imagemagick to work correctly.

I created a `fonts` directory in my project and placed all of my fonts there. Also in that directory I created a `fonts.conf` file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/var/task/fonts/</dir>
  <cachedir>/tmp/fonts-cache/</cachedir>
  <config></config>
</fontconfig>
```

And then in my (node.js based) handler function before shelling out to call pandoc I set an ENV var to tell fontconfig where to find the fonts.

```
process.env.FONTCONFIG_PATH='/var/task/fonts'
```

After doing that I can refer to a font, like `Bitter`, in my template by name (just `Bitter`) and then pandoc/xelatex/fontconfig/whatever knows which version of the font to use (like `Bitter-Bold.otf` vs `Bitter-Italic.otf`) based on the styling that any bit of text is supposed to have.

I figured this out based on the tips in this project for getting RSVG to work with custom fonts on Lambda: https://github.com/claudiajs/rsvg-convert-aws-lambda-binary/blob/master/README.md#using-custom-fonts

Comment: Thank you, this is what led me to the solution using WkHtmlToPdf. I was unsure about how to refer to the font in my template (CSS).

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The reason you can even use Imagemagick with your lambda is because AWS Lambda team had pre-installed this library on their containers.

This is true for Lambda's running on NodeJS - which has libraries for operating the Imagemagick installed on your OS but not running it itself.

You should examine using C# / Java runtimes - which might have the Imagemagick library that you can add to your Lambda (not sure about that).

Comment: hi...so Imagemagick is pre installed, can imagemagick functions be used via PHP, like how we normally use it, EX: `$img = newImagick('image.jpg');`

Comment: To give a little more background, I need imagemagick for moviepy. I've added my own Imagemagick to my lambda package and then I'm instructing moviepy to point to the right version of Imagemagick like so:

    from moviepy.config import change_settings
    IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY = os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, 'imagemagick/bin/magick')

Comment: You can call ImageMagick from Python using a subprocess call. See https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=32920. If using ImageMagick 7, then change convert to magick.