# How to use imagick with php in aws lambda?

Tags: php, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Currently Amazon lambda does supports only node.js and python.
I found a official document to run php in lambda. link is https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/

I have successfully ran php in lambda. But the problem is I don't know how to use imagick with php. 
I have installed imagick on my EC2 with following commands

```
sudo yum install pecl make ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel php-devel gcc re2c
sudo pecl install imagick
```

running following command returns my imagemagick versions

```
convert --version
```

Outputs

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 2016-06-22 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

I am running my php with php binaries in node.js

```
process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'];

const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

exports.handler = function(event, context,callback) {

    //var php = spawn('php',['helloLambda.php']); //local debug only
    var php = spawn('php-7-bin/bin/php',['imagick.php']);
    var output = "";

    //send the input event json as string via STDIN to php process
    php.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(event));

    //close the php stream to unblock php process
    php.stdin.end();

    //dynamically collect php output
    php.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
          output+=data;
    });

    //react to potential errors
    php.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log("STDERR: "+data);
    });

    //finalize when php process is done.
    php.on('close', function(code) {
            //context.succeed(JSON.parse(output));
            callback(null,output);
    });
}
```

Above PHP is successfully running, Now I'm trying to use imagick with php by replacing var php = spawn('php-7-bin/bin/php',['imagick.php']);

**imagick.php**

```
$image = new Imagick('image.jpg');
$image->thumbnailImage(100, 0);
// Just trying to use imagick function
```

**php.js**

```
process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'];

const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

exports.handler = function(event, context,callback) {

    //var php = spawn('php',['helloLambda.php']); //local debug only
    var php = spawn('php-7-bin/bin/php',['imagick.php']);
    var output = "";

    //send the input event json as string via STDIN to php process
    php.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(event));

    //close the php stream to unblock php process
    php.stdin.end();

    //dynamically collect php output
    php.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
          output+=data;
    });

    //react to potential errors
    php.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log("STDERR: "+data);
    });

    //finalize when php process is done.
    php.on('close', function(code) {
            //context.succeed(JSON.parse(output));
            callback(null,output);
    });
}
```

But it throws following error

```
"\nFatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Imagick' not found in /var/task/imagick.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/task/imagick.php on line 5\n"
```

Comment: convert --version checks Imagemagick is installed NOT Imagick. Imagick is a php API for Imagemagick and is not part of Imagemagick - from what I understand it is a class.

Comment: @Bonzo Yes it is a class of imagemagick. Is there any way to use imagemagic with php in lambda??

Comment: I have no idea what Lambda is but I use Imagemagick on a normal server  with the php exec( ). There is currently another post about Imagemagick and Lambda here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622770/install-a-new-font-on-aws-lamba/43694095#43694095

Comment: @Bonzo Kindly suggest me where I can find docs for using imagick with exec() in php. Is commands are there for all functions of imagick.?

Comment: I would suggest you forget about php for this specific use case. You don't need it, Lambda can `exec` (`spawn`). @Bonzo Lambda is a service from AWS where your code is auto-deployed inside (docker?) containers that are totally hands-off to you, automatically infinitely scaling, billed in fractional seconds of CPU time for each function call you invoke. There's a system image identical to theirs for compiling/testing binaries -- but *everything* your code needs to have on the server must be contained/deployed in a single zip file, including the binaries for e.g. imagemagick and even php itself.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments above, Imageick is a different than ImageMagick (well is more of a wrapper to access it, I *think*). Amazon have a [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/) that I believe you may have followed.

> I am running my php with php binaries in node.js

Which means you're most of the way there. From the above blog post, before you go compile php with `./configure --prefix=/home/ec2-user/php-7-bin/` you need to go compile Imagick for your php, so it is bundled with it. But you need to compile it statically so its included in final code. I believe you may also want to compile ImageMagick statically as well so you don't have to rely on the one installed that it will always be installed.

I don't have the instructions for both of the above anymore, we went down a different route with Magick.NET and wrote our image manipulation tool in C# instead. The methods used in php with Imagick and with Magick.NET were easily convertable but it also depends on the rest of your enviroment.